# How do I attach separate PDF's to contact list email addresses using Python?

Tags: python, email, pdf, contact-list

I have written a script that sends individual emails to all contacts in an Excel table. The table looks like this:

```
Names Emails             PDF
Name1 Email1@email.com   PDF1.pdf 
Name2 Email2@email.com   PDF2.pdf
```

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
from string import Template

import pandas as pd

e = pd.read_excel("Contacts.xlsx")

emails = e['Email'].values
PDF = e['PDF'].values
print(emails, PDF)

server = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.outlook.com', port=587) 
server.starttls()
server.login('sender_email','sender_password')

msg = ("""
Hi there

Test message

Thankyou
""")

subject = "Send emails with attachment"

body = "Subject: {}\n\n{}".format(subject,msg)   
for emails in emails:
    server.sendmail('sender_email',emails,body)

print("Emails sent successfully")

server.quit()
```

**Question:** How can I look up the correct attachment (column 3) for each e-mail address (column 2) and attach it to the email using Python?

Comment: You just need to write a "for" loop over the rows, and treat each one separately, instead of bundling all the email addresses and PDFs together as you're doing now.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little changes , and make you sure the pdf field has the pdf path
Edit:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
from string import Template
import pandas as pd

#e = pd.read_csv("Contacts.csv")
e = pd.read_excel("Contacts.xlsx")
server = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.outlook.com', port=587)
server.starttls()
server.login('yourmail@mail.com','yourpass')

body = ("""
Hi there

Test message

Thankyou
""")
subject = "Send emails with attachment"
fromaddr='yourmail@mail.com'
#body = "Subject: {}\n\n{}".format(subject,msg)
#Emails,PDF
for index, row in e.iterrows():
    print (row["Emails"]+row["PDF"])
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
    filename = row["PDF"]
    toaddr = row["Emails"]
    attachment = open(row["PDF"], "rb")
    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)
    msg.attach(part)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
    #server.sendmail('sender_email',emails,body)

print("Emails sent successfully")

server.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is great, however I notice the PDFs are accumulating on the loop. So for example, the first email address gets sent the first PDF. But the second email gets sent the second PDF PLUS the PDF attributable to the first email. Do you know how to resolve this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is strange...I tested without problem...but with a csv file

Comment: ok , I found the error ...sorry...Now is edited , I put the MIMEMultipart inside the loop