# Sending Email to different recipients with different file attachments using python

Tags: python, email, email-attachments, smtplib

Hi I'm new to learning python and I'm trying to send emails to a few hundred different recipients with a different attachment to each of them. I have the recipients data in a database and a folder with all the files in it.

Database has supplier id, name and email

[Database example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVjdA.png)

The folder structure is just one folder with all the files in it for example :

[Folder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sicd6.png)

Supplier files folder --

123.xls

123.pdf

456.xls

789.pdf

any direction on how to get started with this is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-send-email/  ...

Comment: first try and map each of the supplier and the email.. have it as a dict maybe.. and follow the  above to send an email

Answer (score 1):

In this example I will use an answer that I gave to another question ([How do I attach separate PDF's to contact list email addresses using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58575615/how-do-i-attach-separate-pdfs-to-contact-list-email-addresses-using-python/58576568#comment103476627_58576568)) , I use a csv file that contains the addresses and the file path that corresponds to it like img bellow :

users.csv :

[image]

folder with csv files :

[image]

And this is the code:

```
import smtplib, ssl
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
from string import Template
import pandas as pd

# read the file containing the database with the mail and the corresponding file
e = pd.read_csv("users.csv")
# In this example we will use gmail 
context = ssl.create_default_context()
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465,context=context)
server.login('mymail@gmail.com','mypass')

body = ("""
Hi there

Test message

Thankyou
""")
subject = "Send emails with attachment"
fromaddr='mymail@gmail.com'

for index, row in e.iterrows():
    print (row["Emails"]+row["csv"])
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
    filename = row["csv"]
    toaddr = row["Emails"]
    attachment = open(row["csv"], "rb")
    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)
    msg.attach(part)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)

print("Emails sent successfully")

server.quit()
```

if you use a gmail account, check that you have it permissions to send emails from other types of clients (https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255)